# Improved link-only answer audit failed

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, link-only-answers

I just failed this audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4883606

Which was a link-only answer, had a comment to that effect, and was edited to include the content of the link. I can't say for sure that it was a *great* answer after the edit, but it did not appear to me that it matched any of the deletion criteria (though according to the system, it was already deleted).

Am I missing something important, did I just not read it correctly? I can't review because the answer isn't visible in my "STOP Look and listen dialog" (ironically enough)!

Comment: I'm not sure about the "spam" label, but it doesn't appear to be an appropriate answer, because (1) it's a debugging checklist, not an answer; (2) the poster probably is not authorized to put that content on SO under the CC license - the source page says "VerySimple © 2014. All Rights Reserved".

Comment: @AndrewMedico, I could understand (1) being a reason for deletion (potentially), as to (2), is that something we are expected to check for when looking at links+relevant information type answers? Overall still seems like a very tricky audit...

Comment: I'm not sure what the official policy is - the moderator who deleted it could probably explain.