# Gap between moderation theory and practice for link-only answer deletion

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, link-only-answers

Are reviewers currently too harsh in votes to delete link-only answers?

### Theory

I'm aware this has been a topic for debate for a long time, from [Your answer is in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) through [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer) and a bunch ([α](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318756/bring-some-consistency-to-the-flagging-and-deletion-of-link-only-answers) [β](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255864/improved-link-only-answer-audit-failed) [γ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338758/missing-standard-flag-for-link-only-answers)) of user complaints here.

The documentation on the main site seems pretty clear to me:

> **When should I vote to delete an answer?**
>
> You may vote to delete answers in the following cases:
>
> - The answer is extremely low quality: There is little to no scope for improvement
> - The answer doesn't attempt to answer the question; it may be a comment or a separate question altogether.

So, if the answer actually tries to address the problem, and has some scope for improvement even if poor, it should not be deleted.

### Practice

So, with that in mind, I run into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42575967/fingerprintmanagercompat-ishardwaredetected-return-false-in-targetapi-25/43618556) in the Low Quality Posts review queue:

> FingerprintManagerComact.isDetected does not work correctly Please vote for this bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37132365

This is clearly not a *good* answer, but looking at [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42575967/fingerprintmanagercompat-ishardwaredetected-return-false-in-targetapi-25), it does contain two important bits of information:

- The issue the questioner is seeing is due to an upstream bug.
- Through the link, specifics of the change that causes the problem and ongoing debate.

So, I vote to keep so I can edit the answer to include the current status from the bug... but boom, turns out the thing is already deleted.

So, now the site is left with a question with one (unhelpful) answer and no link to the upstream bug that might actually be of use to anyone running into the problem. This does not seem like a good outcome for users to me.

Comment: That "answer" seems to be more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: There is no *answer* to "how do I make this work" till an upstream bug is fixed, so until then the answer *is* the bug.

Comment: ["That city's littering laws are too strict. I'd leave, but for some reason every other city is covered in garbage."](https://twitter.com/drob/status/618120713522802688)

Comment: ["90% of everything is garbage"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon's_law)

Comment: @gz.: so we shouldn't take out the trash then? Yes, if this is trash, we take it out.

Comment: If that's the prevaling moderator attitude now, you should edit your answer to the FAQ. The post "attempts to answer the question", and had scope for improvement.

Comment: Not hard to salvage the info.  Done.

Comment: nb, that answer seems to have caught a spam flag, which may have caused its deletion.

Comment: That was deleted by a moderator, not by reviewers.

Comment: related: [Failed and banned for user who answered the question correctly?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288592/839601) and [There is no shame in using “Skip”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/839601)

Answer (score 9):

That answer was not deleted in accordance with the [canonical "Another Castle" guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). As you note, "this is an upstream bug" *is* an explanation. It's not very good, since it contains no workaround or details of how and when the bug strikes, but it *is* an answer. The link adds more information to allow tracking, but unfortunately that causes oversensitive reviewers to immediately think "link-only!" and delete.

This is just as wrong as it was when Shog wrote that post originally. But these days, there's a *lot* of posts that get deleted that way, many of which show up later as audits in various queues, blindly passing on bad guidance through inapplicable auto-comments to more reviewers, who will then continue the cycle.